# How to get _mm256_rcp_pd in AVX2?

Tags: simd, avx2

For some reason `_mm256_rcp_pd` is not in AVX or AVX2.

In AVX512 we got `_mm256_rcp14_pd`.

Is there a way to get a fast approximate reciprocal in double precision on AVX2? Are we supposed to convert to single precision and then back?

Comment: You’re supposed to divide numbers with `_mm256_div_pd`. These approximate instructions, `rcpps` and `rsqrtps`, are only there because on early SSE processors like Pentium 3 division and square root were very slow, like 40-60 cycles. They became much faster since then. For instance, on AMD Zen 3 `vdivpd` takes ≤13 cycles. If you downcast your vector to FP32, use `_mm_rcp_ps`, then upcast back, these 3 instructions will take 6+3+4=13 cycles, no reason to do that.

Comment: @Soonts: "no reason" except maybe throughput instead of latency; conversion and `vrcpps` are fully pipelined.  But `vdivpd` is also partially pipelined on recent CPUs, with throughput better than latency although not 1/clock.  If you're considering something low-precision like this, it probably means your data should have been `float` in the first place; at least the result so you only have to convert *to* float, not back to double.

Comment: Casting down to `float` can cause over- or underflows. So for a good simulation of `rcp14_pd`, you'd also have to also manually calculate the exponent -- unless you know that your input range is limited.

Answer (score 2):

With some integer-cast-hacking, and a  Newton–Raphson refinement step, you can get a somewhat accurate approximation with 3 uops. Latency is probably not too good, since this involves mixing integer and double operations. But it should be much better than `divpd`.
This solution also assumes that all inputs are normalized doubles.

```
__m256d fastinv(__m256d y)
{
    // exact results for powers of two
    __m256i const magic = _mm256_set1_epi64x(0x7fe0'0000'0000'0000);
    // Bit-magic: For powers of two this just inverts the exponent, 
    // and values between that are linearly interpolated 
    __m256d x = _mm256_castsi256_pd(_mm256_sub_epi64(magic,_mm256_castpd_si256(y)));

    // Newton-Raphson refinement: x = x*(2.0 - x*y):
    x = _mm256_mul_pd(x, _mm256_fnmadd_pd(x, y, _mm256_set1_pd(2.0)));

    return x;
}
```

With the constants above, the inverse is exact for powers of two, but has an error of ~1.44% near `sqrt(2)`.

If you fine-tune the `magic` constant as well as the `2.0` constant or add another NR-step, you can increase the accuracy.

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/f7YhnhT96

Comment: I have not expected that, but it seems your version is about 8 times faster: https://quick-bench.com/q/_guRGzj2vVf1ha0J8J3ALJfJSr4